# How to Trigger an Databricks Notebook using Python Flask Api

Tags: azure, triggers, flask-restful, azure-databricks

I want to Trigger a Databricks notebbok in my azure account from a flask api function which is running in my local VS Code. I have all the connection parameters like host URL, cluster_id, Token_id except Org_id which i am not able to find and the path of Notebook. How to write a Flask Api to basically trigger (Run) that Databricks Notebook.

Comment: The question is incomplete..

Comment: i edited the question . I Think it might help us now ??, Please let me know if anything else is required

Answer (score 0):

You can call Databricks Rest API from the Flask API like below:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <token_id>',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
}
di={"job_id":int(job),"notebook_params":{"id":str(id)}} //Databricks paramters

resp = requests.post('<Databricks Workspace URL>/api/2.0/jobs/run-now', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

You can get the job id in the Job tab of databricks

[image]