# How to test simple Flask app on Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure, flask, databricks

When I develop Flask API (hello.py) on my local machine I can easily test it with

```
> set FLASK_APP=hello
> python -m flask run
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

I would like to do the same when I develop in notebook on Azure Databricks. I wonder if it is possible at all?

Comment: [How to Trigger an Databricks Notebook using Python Flask Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61498685/how-to-trigger-an-databricks-notebook-using-python-flask-api) and [Python Flask App migrate to Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/693628/python-flask-app-migrate-to-databricks.html)

Comment: First question - why do you need to run Flask app on Databricks?

Comment: @AlexOtt, Databricks are now my main development environment. I have no other choice, I wish I could continue developing locally.

Comment: @AlexOtt Perhaps triggering a job that via a REST API?